# Read HL7 cda xml file using Everest Framework .Net

Tags: c#, hl7, cda, hl7-v3

I have read that everest framework support HL7 CDA V3 Xml file but I cant find any examples on how to use this framework to read data from xml files.
Does anybody know how to do it ?
Thanks.
Framework link: http://everest.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples which hint at this, and the guide book has some good examples.  In the code documentation there is an example which reads from a string (see XmlIts1Formatter.Parse's documentation), which you can adapt to any XmlReader:

```
using(XmlStateReader xr = new XmlStateReader(XmlReader.Create(@"C:\path-to-file.xml")))
{
    var fmtr = new XmlIts1Formatter();
    fmtr.ValidateConformance = false;
    fmtr.GraphAides.Add(new ClinicalDocumentDatatypeFormatter());
    var parseResult = fmtr.Parse(xr, typeof(ClinicalDocument));
    // There is a variable called structure which will contain your
    var cda = parseResult.Structure as ClinicalDocument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this framework, but me advice for parsing HL7 CDA, is doing it using XML technologies like Xpath. Better performance and simpler

Greetings,
Martí